# Why does double quoting an array expansion in here document not seem to work here?

Tags: bash, quoting, array, here-document

I have two arrays

```
$ arr1=( 1 2 2 3)
$ arr2=( 2 3 3 4)
```

Why does this generate strange output when I follow the good practice of double quoting an array expansion

```
$ tsort << EOF
> "${arr1[@]}" "${arr2[@]}"
> EOF
"1
"2
2
3
3"
4"
```

whereas this one generates correct results, when I do not follow the good practice? What shall I do? Thanks.

```
$ tsort << EOF
${arr1[@]} ${arr2[@]} 
EOF

1
2
3
4
```

---

I think word splitting is still performed in here document:

```
$ wc -l << EOF
a    
b  
1
EOF
3
```

Comment: Where is word splitting in your example? `wc` receives a single stream and counts newlines in it.

Answer (score 4):

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents):

> [...] all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence `\newline` is ignored, and ‘`\`’ must be used to quote the characters ‘`\`’, ‘`$`’, and ‘`` ` ``’.

It doesn't say anything about removing quotes, or field splitting or filename expansion, so the quotes in a heredoc are taken literally, and don't perform their usual functions.

Comment: Thanks. "It doesn't say anything about removing quotes, or field splitting or filename expansion, so... don't perform their usual functions." I think word splitting is still performed. Otherwise, how the command receives multiple words?

Comment: Who said the command receives multiple words? How do you know the command didn't decide to parse the input into words?

Comment: See my update. If word splitting is unmentioned but still performed, why can't quote removal?

Comment: How does your update prove word splitting is performed?

Answer (score 2):

[The other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482437/108618) is basically "because the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents) says so", but I think there is some *rationale* behind this behavior.

> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only *word* (with no trailing blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the **standard input** […] for a command.
>
> […]
>
> If any part of *word* is quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on *word*, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded. If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion […].

(emphasis mine).

Consider main reasons to quote something in a command line:

1. to tell the shell how to split the line and create a list of arguments (two arguments `a b` vs. one argument `"a b"`);
2. to tell the shell if expansions should be performed (`''` vs. `""` or unquoted).

The first reason doesn't apply while creating a standard input because standard input is a *stream* and there is no concept of number of arguments in it. The second reason could apply but the design choice to control expansions solely by quoting or not quoting *word* (`"EOF"` vs. `EOF`) invalidates it.

> What shall I do?

You shall remember with here document you create a stream. The reasons to use quotes that *wouldn't* appear in it have been invalidated. In effect the premise is every quote you use *should* appear in the stream.

If this worked more as you expected then unescaped quotes would disappear *without making any difference*. I guess here document would then support `\"` and `\'` to denote quotes that should survive. But these would be the only quotes you would really need to use. The current situation simplifies things.

Comment: If the implementations had elected to perform all expansions and quote removal, somebody would have made a rationalisation for that too.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what actually happens here by replacing `tsort` with `cat`:

```
$ arr1=( 1 2 2 3 )
$ arr2=( 2 3 3 4 )
$ cat <<END
> "${arr1[@]}" "${arr2[@]}"
> END
"1 2 2 3" "2 3 3 4"
```

As you can see, the here-document is nothing but a text string with the values of the arrays expanded inside it.  The double quotes come from the double quotes in the document itself (the shell only cares about the `${...}` bit and won't touch the quote characters).

The output when deleting the double quotes would be the same, but without the double quotes,

```
1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4
```

This would be interpreted by `tsort` as the pairs

```
1 2   <-- first two numbers from arr1
2 3   <-- last two numbers from arr1
2 3   <-- first two numbers from arr2
3 4   <-- last two numbers from arr2
```

It's unfortunate that you chose this particular example, as this happens to be exactly the same as

```
1 2   <-- first number from arr1 and arr2
2 3   <-- second number from arr1 and arr2
2 3   <-- etc.
3 4
```

i.e., the entries of each array running down in two columns (one column per array).

To generate this second list (correctly), you can't really use a here-document.  Instead you could use a shell loop:

```
for (( i=0; i<${#arr1[@]}; ++i)); do
    printf '%d %d\n' "${arr1[i]}" "${arr2[i]}"
done | tsort
```